# What is the order of complexity of comparing two python lists?

Tags: python

Assume the lists contain hashable objects only.

BTW, I'm not sure if this question makes sense as I am a complete noob when it comes to complexity and academic stuff.

Comment: The [TimeComplexity](http://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity) entry in the Python wiki should help with this.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The complexity of comparing two lists is O(n) if both lists have length n, and O(1) if the lists have different lengths.

Answer (score 5):

This very much depends on the sense of the word 'comparison'.

If you compare for equality, @Sven-Marnach's answer applies: O(n) for same length, O(1) for different lengths.

Use of a hash function can help you if you compare many lists with each other: it is O(1) for different lists (with different hashes), and may still be O(n) for lists with the same hashes since hash values may clash, and you'll have to make a real comparison. This can be alleviated by use of more than one hash function, so the probability of a clash is reduced dramatically.

Note that it still takes O(n) to compute a hash value for a list of length n, so no free lunch here.

If you want to compare two lists for similarity, you'll probably need [Levenshtein distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance) which is quadratic in time in the straightforward case but can be made linear by lazy evaluation, probably at a great memory expense.

If you want to compute the complete list of changes to do to make one list from another ([`diff`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diff)), it is quadratic in the best implementation mentioned in Wikipedia.

Answer (score 0):

O(n).
For a given choice of algorithm, the answer can not be - "it depends".
It is always a definitive answer for the worst-case scenario. That is why it (Big-O notation) - is called - 'asymptotic analysis'.