# loop on long sequence in python with minimum time complexity in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have two DNA sequences (long sequences) I want to iterate onto them.
I tried traditional for loop but it takes linear time so it has big complexity so I want to find a way to loop on these two sequences and compare between characters without linear time, is there any way to do that ?
*update*
I want to compare between each character in two sequences
*update 2 :*
this is code which I tried

```
for i in range(0,len(seqA)):
    if seqA[i]==seqB[i]:
        print("similar")
    else :
        print("not similar")
```

and this is a sample of DNA sequences which I want to compare between it

```
seqA = "AT-AC-TCT-GG--TTTCT--CT----TCA---G-A-T--C-G--C--AT-A----AATC-T-T--T-CG-CCTT-T-T---A---C--TA-A--A---G-ATTTCCGT-GGAG-AGG-A-AC---AACTCT-G-AG-T--CT---TA--AC-CCA---ATT-----T--T-TTG-AG--CCTTGCCTT-GGCAA-GGCT--A---"
seqB = "ATCGCTTCTCGGCCTTT-TGGCTAAGATCAAGTGTAGTATCTGTTCTTATCAGTTTAAT-ATCTGATACGTCC-TCTATCCGAGGACAATATATTAAATGGATTT---TTGGAGCAGGGAGA-TGGAA---TAGGAGCTTGCTCCGT-CCACTCCACGCA-TCGACCTGGTATTGCAGTACC-T-CC--AGG-AACGG-TGCACCC"
```

Comment: Just clarifying, do you want to compare each character between 2 long sequences in a time faster than O(n) ? Or are you looking to compare only specific chars ?

Comment: yes I want to compare between each character in time faster than O(n)

Comment: Post what code you have tried, your sample data and your expected output, so we can see what exactly you are trying to do.  It is highly unlikely that you can do better than linear time.

Comment: @MohamedHoosam all I can do is direct you to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11313999/6620283), the time complexity to compare two equal lists (or each element in the lists) is going to be O(n) since you have to make a minimum of n comparisons.

Answer (score 0):

If you want this: a sequence that tells you for each position whether they are equal at that point (assuming they are equally long):

```py
result = "".join(
    1 if a == seqB[i] else 0
    for (i, a) in enumerate(seqA)
)
```

Not sure how useful `result` is. What if both sequences are similar, but one of them has deleted a letter? By this measure the sequences will then be very dissimilar.

The Levenshtein edit-distance is a captures the intuition of similarity better, but is much more costly to compute.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance

You could chop up the sequences in chunks of 100 letters, and perform Levenshtein on each pair of chunks.

This library has worked well for me, working on ancient texts, not DNA (I did billions of pairs of chunks in a few hours):
https://github.com/ztane/python-Levenshtein